# 404 when accessing the example() data of vaex

Tags: python, vaex

When accessing the

```
  vaex.example()
```

as documented on the `vaex` sphinx docs home page  https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It serves up a 404:

```
import vaex; 
df = vaex.example(); 
dfn = df[0:5][['x','y']]; 
dfn.describe()


Downloading http://vaex.astro.rug.nl/data/helmi-dezeeuw-2000-10p.hdf5 to /Users/steve/.vaex/data/helmi-dezeeuw-2000-10p.hdf5
--2020-08-29 17:12:10--  http://vaex.astro.rug.nl/data/helmi-dezeeuw-2000-10p.hdf5
Resolving vaex.astro.rug.nl (vaex.astro.rug.nl)... 129.125.6.3
Connecting to vaex.astro.rug.nl (vaex.astro.rug.nl)|129.125.6.3|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://vaex.io/data/helmi-dezeeuw-2000-10p.hdf5 [following]
--2020-08-29 17:12:11--  https://vaex.io/data/helmi-dezeeuw-2000-10p.hdf5
Resolving vaex.io (vaex.io)... 172.67.69.63, 104.26.0.195, 104.26.1.195
Connecting to vaex.io (vaex.io)|172.67.69.63|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-08-29 17:12:11 ERROR 404: Not Found.

wget failed, using urlretrieve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/__init__.py", line 575, in example
```

Is there an updated url for that dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your vaex version,

```
pip install --upgrade vaex
```

For example, in v1.0.0 it tries to download the data from

`http://vaex.astro.rug.nl/data/helmi-dezeeuw-2000-10p.hdf5`

while in version 3.0.0 it downloads it from

`https://github.com/vaexio/vaex-datasets/releases/download/v1.0/helmi-dezeeuw-2000-FeH-v2-10percent.hdf5`.

Comment: thx!  `$python -c "import vaex; df = vaex.example(); dfn = df[0:5][['x','y']]; print(dfn.describe())"
                        x                  y
dtype             float32            float32
count                   5                  5
NA                      0                  0
mean   2.1761375606060027  4.632662558555603
std               3.36709            4.05373
min              -2.12026          -0.396929
max               7.21719            11.9947`